# Limitation in Oracle to call a local procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, duplicates, extend

I have executed below block in SQL*PLUS and it successfully executed the whole block.
Strangely, it inserted only **32768** unique values in the table and remaining **7232** were duplicates.

Please note we have to manually call the local procedure 40k times without using a loop.

```
/*
-- @Hello
-- please create this test table
-- on your database schema

CREATE TABLE my_table (
   num       NUMBER,
   upd_dt   DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
)
/
*/

DECLARE
   TYPE my_tp IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
   my_nest_t my_tp := my_tp ();

   PROCEDURE add (
      p_num   IN      NUMBER
   )
   AS
   BEGIN
      my_nest_t.EXTEND;
      my_nest_t (my_nest_t.LAST) := NULL;
      my_nest_t (my_nest_t.LAST).num := p_num;
   END add;
BEGIN
   add (1);
   add (2);
   add (3);
   add (4);
   /*
   -- @Hello
   -- this way manually write the call to
   -- the local proc 40000 times
   -- I used CONNECT BY LEVEL to generate the script
   -- SELECT ' add (p_num=>' || level || ');' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 40001
   -- use this query only to generate the 40k rows of code
   */
   add (39999);
   add (40000);
   
   IF my_nest_t.COUNT < 40000 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, '@Hello - please call PROCEDURE add 40000 times as mentioned above');
   END IF;

   FORALL i IN 1.. my_nest_t.COUNT
      INSERT INTO my_table (num)
      VALUES (my_nest_t (i).num);
   COMMIT;
END;
/

/*
-- @Hello
*/

-- 40000, 32768
SELECT COUNT (1),
               COUNT (DISTINCT num)
FROM    my_table
```

Comment: Have you got a trigger on the table which is assigning/overriding the suppled `num` value, from a sequence which has `maxvalue 32768` and `cycle`? Compare [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35ba5ac60807f40a0ba949fbbbb71d04) with [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1918787076b0d22288b87801e83de935). You aren't raising your exception so the problem isn't with the `add()` or the calls to that; so the insert must be the issue. (Also you can do this with bulk insert, or without any PL/SQL...)

Comment: As you've confirmed this happens with no trigger; if you're on 11gR1 (e.g. 11.1.0.7) it's possible you're hitting a bug, maybe with `forall`; [this looks like a possibility](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=7000281.8) for example. Do you get the correct results if you change that for a `for` loop with individual inserts? You seem to be suggesting that the problem only appears with lots of individual calls, rather than calling in a loop, but it isn't clear if the collection is incorrect before the insert.

Comment: "we have to manually call the local procedure 40k times"... Really? You are MANUALLY calling the procedure 40k times? Like, you press some button 40k times? Hard to believe. Anyway - whatever calls the procedure, are you absolutely sure it does it 40k times?

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski - from other comments, the issue is only seen when the anonymous block has 40000 individual calls to the local `add()` procedure; that's what the OP means by 'manual'. It doesn't happen when 40000 calls are made from a loop, apparently. Which doesn't make much sense, of course.

Comment: @Alex Poole : Even if I use FOR LOOP and INSERT instead of FORALL, still it gives me the same issue. It is really strange but I am not getting any clue. As you suggested, let me check if the issue is specific to the collection or with the INSERT and come back to you.

Comment: I havent read it thoroughly the first time. I'm curious now about the actual values which were inserted. e.g. SELECT num, count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY num HAVING count(*) > 1 or SELECT max(num), min(num) FROM my_table. Also 32768 = 32 * 1024 = 2^15, which is probably not a coincidence. Couldn't reproduce the problem on 19c.

Comment: @Marcin: MAX(num) is 32767, MIN(num) is 0 even though I have not assigned it to the collection. Value at index position 32768 is 0. And value at index 32769 is 1.. then 2.. then 3...and so on till the last index. It is indeed strange though

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on version 12.1.

I believe there are duplicates among calls to add procedure.

Here, how I generated those for tests

```
select 'add(' || level || ');' from dual connect by level <= 40000
```

then I copied them to the plsql block and launched. After that the check-query from you

```
SELECT COUNT (1), COUNT (DISTINCT num)
  FROM    ek_test;
```

displays 40000 for both coleumns.

So my answer is, please check all those 40 thousands of procedure calls and look for   duplicates.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. But yes, I have used the same method (CONNECT BY LEVEL < 40001) to generate unique values for the test. There are no duplicates in my program. But the final output post script execution always return 32768 unique values instead of 40000. Hope you have not done any modifications in the initial code which I shared.

Comment: Hi @ShintoJoy what DB-version and edition  (Express, Standart, Enterprise) are you on?

Comment: @ShintoJoy and please post how did you generate 40 thousand calls. Let's see it too

Comment: I used 2 methods to generate the 40k lines. (1) using the CONNECT BY LEVEL (2) I generated the code in MS Excel by adding numbers from 1 to 40k in column A and formula ="   add("&A1&");"

Comment: @ShintoJoy post them all to your question. Let me know when you've post updated

Comment: SELECT '   add (p_num=>' || level || ');' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 40001

Comment: Let me clarify some more. The issue is not only with exact 40k records. If I try to extend the nested table more than 32768, the next indexes in nested table ( starting from 32769 ) is adding duplicate values starting from 1 ( which is value from index 1 )

Comment: @ShintoJoy just tried on 11.2 Standart edition. Same result - both columns are equal 40000. Sorry, There is nothing I can add without seeing code you've used to generate 40000 calls

Comment: DB is Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition

Comment: @ShintoJoy I got it but 11.2 SE is the most close I have access to. I don't think edition will make difference here. As I said, I can't say anything more until you've posted code you're using to generate 40000 calls

Comment: Hi I already mentioned the code which I used to generate the 40000 calls in comment

Comment: @ShintoJoy sorry did not see that. I've tried with your code and still have all cols equal to 40000. Can you perhaps reproduce it on dbfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for trying at your end. Let me check with the DBA guys if there is any setting at DB level which causes this limitation.

Comment: @ShintoJoy let me know if you find anything out. It's an interesting case you have

Comment: Sure, I have posted on StackOverFlow for the first time because it's so strange issue to me and I am eager to get any clue to this problem. Thank you for showing up and throwing some light. I will definitely keep you posted. 